# Dynamically assign variable in Oracle join statement

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle script. Trying to convert the sql to oracle and trying to execute below script as sample

```
DECLARE v_Removalsql varchar(100);
v_strQuery VARCHAR(1000);
v_Removalsql := 'Node.ElectronicSerialNumber'
v_strQuery := 'select * from ConsumerMessage join Node on 
ConsumerMessage.ElectronicSerialNumber = :name' ;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_strQuery using v_Removalsql
```

when I execute the above script it gives below error as below

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
>
> - constant exception
> - table long double ref
> - char time timestamp interval date binary national character
> - nchar
>
>   6550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>
> Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: I see many issues in your code; you need a BEGIN...END to wrap a PLSQL block; you are missing a ';'; your query makes a join with no join condition; the dynamic code is not necessary here; ... I would recommend you to start with the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/apps/search/search.jsp?category=database&q=&product=) or with a good book/tutorial.

Comment: @Aleksej I believe the OP's intention is to dynamically assign which column is used in the join condition. I'm not sure why, as this seems like an odd requirement, but hey-ho.

Comment: It does look like that, but if so you can't do that with a bind variable anyway, it would have to be concatenated. Of course, it isn't getting that far. And if it was the dynamic query wouldn't actually be executed anyway as there is no *[bulk collect] into* clause... You need to think about where the results of that query are supposed to go.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a very strange request - normally your join conditions are fixed!

Anyway, as Alex Poole mentioned in a comment above, you can't use bind variables when you're trying to specify the table name, column names, where clauses etc; you can only use it where you might use a literal value. If you need to dynamically specify table names, column names etc, you need to be careful about sql injection - you definitely don't want someone to be able to hijack your procedure for nefarious purposes!

Here's one way you could do this (I have used a ref cursor to demonstrate; this would work with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` too, but you'd have to specify where you want the data to be stored into, again, as previously mentioned by Alex):

```
DECLARE
  v_Removalsql varchar(100);
  v_strQuery VARCHAR(1000);
  v_refcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  v_Removalsql := 'Node.ElectronicSerialNumber'
  v_strQuery := 'select * from ConsumerMessage join Node on ConsumerMessage.ElectronicSerialNumber = :name';

  -- check the string to be concatenated is a valid qualified sql name format
  -- this helps to avoid sql injection, but doesn't check whether the referenced
  -- object exists or not, so if it doesn't the dynamic query will still fail.
  dbms_assert.qualified_sql_name(v_remvoalsql);

  -- Now we can go ahead and replace the string ":name" with the new string
  v_strQuery := REPLACE(v_strQuery, ':name', v_removalsql);

  -- Finally, we can open a ref cursor for the dynamic sql:
  OPEN v_refcur FOR v_strQuery;
END;
/
```

Another way would be to not use `:name` in your sql statement and simply concatenate the separate elements of your query, e.g.:

```
open v_refcur for v_select_clause || chr(10) ||
                  v_from_clause || chr(10) ||
                  v_where_clause;
```

Just make sure you ensure any parameters you build into the string are checked to make sure they meet the Oracle naming standard!